# Magento 2 Rest api to create order not adding shipping address

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, php-7

> I am trying to create an order using magento 2 rest api.But the
>   shipping address is not adding with order details.Because of no
>   shipping address the order is in incomplete format
>
> http://127.0.0.1/netmeds_mage/rest/V1/orders/create
>
> ```
> Method : PUT
> ```
>
> This is the json request :
>
> > {"entity":{"base_currency_code":"INR","base_discount_amount":0,"base_grand_total":38,"base_shipping_amount":5,"base_shipping_incl_tax":5,"base_shipping_tax_amount":0,"base_shipping_discount_amount":0,"base_subtotal":33,"base_subtotal_incl_tax":33,"base_total_due":38,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_order_rate":1,"discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,"base_discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,"shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,"customer_is_guest":0,"customer_dob":"Jan
> >     18,
> >     1987","customer_email":"sharvesh@gmail.com","customer_firstname":"Sharvesh","customer_gender":1,"customer_group_id":1,"customer_id":4,"customer_lastname":"CP","customer_note_notify":1,"discount_amount":0,"email_sent":1,"global_currency_code":"INR","grand_total":38,"order_currency_code":"INR","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","shipping_amount":5,"shipping_tax_amount":0,"shipping_description":"Flat
> >     Rate -
> >     Fixed","shipping_discount_amount":0,"shipping_incl_tax":5,"state":"pending","status":"pending","store_currency_code":"INR","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_order_rate":0,"store_id":1,"subtotal":33,"subtotal_incl_tax":33,"total_due":38,"total_item_count":1,"total_qty_ordered":1,"tax_amount":0,"weight":1,"items":[{"base_original_price":33,"base_price":33,"base_price_incl_tax":33,"base_row_total":33,"base_row_total_incl_tax":33,"name":"Endeavor
> >     Daytrip
> >     Backpack","original_price":33,"price":33,"price_incl_tax":33,"product_id":11,"product_type":"simple","qty_ordered":1,"row_total":33,"row_total_incl_tax":33,"sku":"24-WB06","store_id":1,"weight":1}],"billing_address":{"address_type":"billing","city":"Chennai","company":"Netmeds","country_id":"IN","customer_address_id":4,"email":"sharvesh@gmail.com","firstname":"Sharvesh","lastname":"C","postcode":"600117","region":"Tamilnadu","street":["6A,4th
> >     street,Keelkattalai"],"telephone":"9840626148"},"payment":{"amount_ordered":38,"base_amount_ordered":38,"base_shipping_amount":5,"method":"checkmo","shipping_amount":5},"status_histories":[],"extension_attributes":{"shipping_assignments":[{"shipping":{"address":{"address_type":"shipping","city":"Chennai","company":"Netmeds","country_id":"IN","customer_address_id":4,"email":"sharvesh@gmail.com","firstname":"Sharvesh","lastname":"C","postcode":"600117","region":"Tamilnadu","street":["6A,4th
> >     street,Keelkattalai"],"telephone":"9840626148"},"method":"flatrate_flatrate","total":{"base_shipping_amount":5,"base_shipping_incl_tax":5,"shipping_amount":5,"shipping_incl_tax":5},"extension_attributes":[]},"items":[{"base_original_price":33,"base_price":33,"base_price_incl_tax":33,"base_row_total":33,"name":"Endeavor
> >     Daytrip
> >     Backpack","original_price":33,"price":33,"price_incl_tax":33,"product_id":11,"product_type":"simple","qty_ordered":1,"row_total":33,"row_total_incl_tax":33,"sku":"24-WB06","store_id":1,"weight":1}],"extension_attributes":[]}],"applied_taxes":[],"item_applied_taxes":[],"converting_from_quote":true}}}

whether am missing anything or i need to add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have found the solution and worked for me
>
> pls refer this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5544

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same issue. Later on, I found that we have to send a valid address according to the country configured in your store configuration.

Comment: No it is not working,still getting the same problem

Comment: have found the solution and worked for me..pls refer this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5544